# CakePHP not rendering views for some controllers on live server

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem, that I can't figure out.

I made an app with `CakePHP` that work's perfectly fine on localhost (via XAMPP), but has strange issue on live server.
There are (obviously) many controllers in my app, and the problem is - some of them are not rendering any view whatsoever! They output neither proper content, nor any error data - simply empty page (no layout either). About half of them is working fine, and the other half - not.

I have no idea what might that be, so that's why I'm here - any ideas?

Comment: Did you have real error reporting on (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`)?

Comment: Your first step would be to look at CakePHP logs. What version of Cake are you using?

Comment: Please mention `version` when you ask a question on cakephp. Make use of `debug mode` in `core.php`.

Comment: I am using Cake 2.5.2.
Debug is set to 2 in core.php.
Error log does not contain any information about that error.
I added "error_reporting(E_ALL);" to bootstrap.php - still nothing.

Comment: Check the apache log file, and the cake error log file to see if there are any errors. Did you develop it in Windows and now host it on linux?

Comment: I don't have access to apache log file. Cake error log file contains no info about that error. Yes, I developed my app in Windows and I suspect that my current server is hosted on Linux.

Comment: Come on - no ideas at all?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old thread, but I'm replying this as a possible answer and solutions for other people who might have the same problem.

1. What you should do when you have this problem is to check the error log inside `/app/tmp/logs`. From there you can perhaps see what cause the error.
2. Make sure your debug is set to `2` for all error reporting to be displayed if any. The debug can be turned on in `app/Config/core.php`.
3. From the logs, you might see the error is with the maximum memory reached. For this, you'll need to fix your code and optimize it.
4. Please check if your URL rewriting `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your live server. Some server might require you to set it up yourself.

> A piece of advice, always check with your error logs, it always show you what the problems are and can help you solving it easier.